# Netbeans and working with "Compiled Code"

Tags: java, netbeans-7

[image]

(better image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nP1DF.jpg)

I opened up a `.java` file (not `.class`) in Netbeans and I'm confronted by these blocks of "Compiled code". I have been tasked with refactoring this code so that we can make some changes, but every method has this compiled code blocks.

When I double-click on one of them it expands and shows stuff like

```
* 6: astore_2
* 7: aload_0
* 8: ifnull        93
```

What are these, and how should I begin to understand what the code is doing?
There is no documentation anywhere and the programmer that wrote this left a decade ago and no one really knows how it works.

Comment: That's JVM bytecode friend.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings

Comment: You can take a look at JAD (http://www.varaneckas.com/jad/) if you have compile classes you'd like to turn into Java source code. Your mileage may vary with this tool

Comment: Is there a reason why a java source file would have these bytecodes? For example why might someone do it like this, or how they would even do it in the first place.

Comment: It is not the source code, it is already compiled. If you have access to the source, you need to link it with your project.

Comment: I think the OP is saying that the .java files contain bytecode - is that true, or are you looking at the .class files?

Comment: I am looking at the .java file. The class and methods are defined as usual, except the body of each method is just byte code.

Comment: That's not really possible. It's more likely you don't have source attached to a library you're trying to examine.

Comment: @DaveNewton That's also possible. I am using netbean's "go to declaration/source" functions to get an idea how the application is structured, so maybe I am just missing something. What kind of files should I be looking for in this case? Class files? dll's?

Comment: @Keikoku You'd look for the source of the compiled class you're opening.

Comment: I looked at where the class was being imported from and it was in a different package. I went to find that package and then found the source code for the file, and it showed up fine. I guess the issue was that it was just in a different package.

Comment: It seems possible that Netbeans is working with an already compiled `.class` file, and you were tricked into thinking it is a `.java` file because it creates one in a Netbeans `cache` folder, and opens that, and shows the filename title in the tab in bold. Should you hover your mouse to the title it shall tip you with the full path, which I expect to contain words `Netbeans` and `cache` and postfixed `(read-only)`.